# Prove that $D_{-r}=-D_{r}$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm thinking of constructing my dedekind cuts this way and showcasing they are equivalent. Am I on the right track?

$D_{-r}=\left \{ x \in \mathbb{Q}|x>-r \right \}$ and $ -D_{r}=\left \{ -x \in \mathbb{Q}|-x>r \right \} \Rightarrow x =r \Rightarrow D_{-r}=-D_{r}$

Comment: From my prof's lecture notes: "Think of a cut C as the set of all rational numbers to the left of some point in the real line.
In other words, a cut is an open half-line of rational numbers."   Thus your cuts $D_{-r}$ and $D_r$ need to switch form to be in line with the canonical definition.

Comment: So, I simply need to switch my set notation for $D_{-r}$ and $-D_{r}$

Comment: If you are able to reference the reals, yeah it’s that simple.

Comment: You have used slightly different convention for a Dedekind cut, but it's ok if you set up all the definitions using this convention.